# Where to hire a graphics designer for mobile app?

Tags: interface-design, ios, hiring

My friend and I are making iOS apps and we have are not graphic designers. We have no idea how to do any of that stuff.

Where can we find a graphic designer and how much would he/she cost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cost of a designer is going to depend on that designers experience and work history. I would say on average a jr. designer is going to be in the range of $20-35 an hour, a designer is going to be $35-60 and an senior designer is going to be anywhere from $60-125. Those figures will change depending on your location. For example a sr. designer in NYC is going to charge more then a sr. designer in a smaller town. As to where to find them, you can look at portfolio sites such as [BeHance](https://www.behance.net/) or [Dribble](https://dribbble.com/). On those sites you can look around for a style that you are interested in inquire about prices from the designer. I hope this helpful. Good luck with your app!

Comment: Thank you so much! I would like it but I don't have enough reputation.